# Problem making a player respawn at particular location

Tags: box2d

I have a player which moves on applying force. If my player dies by any reason (like getting hit by enemy or bullet ), i hide the player for some time until restart is not pressed.If restart is pressed i use the same instance of player and change the position and angle of player to my desired position where i want player to re spawn .

Player get re spawned at desired position correctly, but if player had any amount of linear velocity or force applied left before it died, it moves a bit until its velocity comes to 0.

```
//In contact listner when player health <0

    bodyB.active=false;
    bodyB.dead=true;
    let filter=bodyB.bodyFixture.GetFilterData();
    filter.maskBits =0;
    filter.groupIndex = -1;
    bodyB.bodyFixture.SetFilterData(filter);

    filter=bodyB.headFixture.GetFilterData();
    filter.maskBits =0 ;
    filter.groupIndex = -1;
    bodyB.headFixture.SetFilterData(filter);
    filter=null;

    bodyB.health=100;
    bodyB.powerUps={};
    bodyB.score=0;

    //On respawn
    players[p_present].body.SetPositionAndAngle( new b2Vec2(150/scale,150/scale),0 );
    players[p_present].body.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0,0));
```

My question is how can i restrict the player not to move on re spawn.

I tried applying setLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0,0)) but its not doing anything.

Comment: Could you post your current code for respawning?

Comment: Yes if you could post your whole code the would be useful - or a minimal example where it doesnt work. What you have suggested (setLinearVelocity) should work - it works in my game using Box2D in Python